# openGL texture bind stretching and warping

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I am trying to bind a texture to a polygon pixel perfect (draw part of texture but nothing bigger than the polygon itself)

for example (edit: those are Polygon's in picture not Quads)
[image: example]

my code is as follows

```
//example usage
// drawRectangle((1D * 100D) + 110D, 5, 0D, 25);
//draws a 100px width, 20px height, 0px from left most screen and 5px from top most screen
public static void drawRectangle(double par1, double par2, double par3, double par4)
    {
        //glRectd(par1, par2, par3, par4);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        {
            glVertex2d(par1, par2);
            glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
            glVertex2d(par3, par2);
            glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
            glVertex2d(par3, par4);
            glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
            glVertex2d(par1, par4);
            glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
```

openGL initiation code

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, finals.GAME_WIDTH, finals.GAME_HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thing is texture coordiantes are normalized to [0..1] range you should make tex coords dependent on polygon size, and tex size, like this:

```
public static void drawRectangle(double par1, double par2, double par3, double par4,
    double width, double height)
{
    //glRectd(par1, par2, par3, par4);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    {
        glVertex2d(par1, par2);
        glTexCoord2d(par1/width, par2/height);
        glVertex2d(par3, par2);
        glTexCoord2d(par2/width, par2/height);
        glVertex2d(par3, par4);
        glTexCoord2d(par3/width, par4/height);
        glVertex2d(par1, par4);
        glTexCoord2d(par1/width, par4/height);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: width being image width and height being image height?

Comment: @JohnM this depends on how you setup rendering, probably yes.

Comment: I prependeded some code to my OP do you mean this? regarding setup rendering

Comment: @JohnM yes, tex width and height.